# Magento 2: Extending a controller but adding an additional parameter in the constructor

Tags: magento2, overrides, controllers

I have been struggling with a problem for a while and hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

I am attempting to extend a native controller by adding my own module. This appears to have worked successfully in the most part. I now have a need to call a bespoke model as an additional parameter in my overriding controllers constructor.

When I attempt to add the new parameter, I am met with the following error:

```
Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Companyname\Modulename\Controller\Result\Index::__construct(), 5 passed in
```

Here is my code for my working controller as an example:

```
namespace Companyname\Modulename\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory;


class Index extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index
{
   protected $layerResolver;
   protected $_queryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $catalogSession,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        QueryFactory $queryFactory,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $catalogSession,
            $storeManager,
            $queryFactory,
            $layerResolver,
            $customer
        );

        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        $this->_queryFactory = $queryFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->layerResolver->create(Resolver::CATALOG_LAYER_SEARCH);

        $query = $this->_queryFactory->get();

        // more code

    }
}
```

Maybe I am going about this is completely the wrong way. if somebody could give me a few pointers I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post the full error message. You only posted partially.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is that **$customer** in your constructor, but I think you should inject it in your constructor, and leave parent as it is (5 parameters)

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $catalogSession,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    QueryFactory $queryFactory,
    Resolver $layerResolver,
    $customer
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $catalogSession,
        $storeManager,
        $queryFactory,
        $layerResolver
    );

    $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    $this->_queryFactory = $queryFactory;
}
```

Another thing, which I am not totally sure, is the order in the code... maybe you'd need to change this to make it work

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $catalogSession,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    QueryFactory $queryFactory,
    Resolver $layerResolver,
    $customer
) {

    $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    $this->_queryFactory = $queryFactory;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $catalogSession,
        $storeManager,
        $queryFactory,
        $layerResolver
    );
}
```

But, let me insist we can't know what class is that **$customer** injected in your constructor. Maybe that's the main problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I had not intended to leave the $customer variable in the constructor. When I tried it before I had this $customer declared as my model class as below but it then gives me an error saying 'too few arguments':

Companyname\Modulename\Model\Customer $customer